# Why can I not use the jar generated by Android Maven apklib in my assembly?

Tags: android, maven, jar, android-library

I use Maven to build my Android library projects, which results in an apklib.
This is less than ideal since it contains the source code, so I have a distribution module (using maven-assembly plugin) that should package the library project with a jar containing the compiled source code in the `libs` directory and an empty `src` directory.

I have included the jar `mygroupid:myartifactid:jar` using a module set include but when I run I find nothing is present in the libs folder. If I change the above to `mygroupid:myartifactid:apklib` then the apklib *is* included. My distribution module has my library module as a dependency, with both the `apklib` type and the `jar` type.

When building I do get the following warning message:

```
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
o  'mygroupid:myartifactid:jar'
```

The Android Maven plugin already attaches a jar: I can see it is created during compile and installed to my local repository on `mvn install`.

So why can I not include it as I would normally?

PS: I know I can include it simply by specifying the file location; but if possible I'd like to not have to specify that myself and do it through a module set.